# How can I get EFrepository to work?

Tags: c#, repository

I am trying out the Repository nuget package from Matthew Shrager:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Repository/

But I can't get Visual Studio to locate the actual class in the namespace. Or the FileSystemRepository which also should be in that package:
I made a small sample project to test it, where you can see the issue:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24914997/repository_issue.jpg

I am sure it's something simple and embarrassing, but I just can't figure it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I figured it out. EFRepository exists in another package. Repository.EntifyFramework. That's. Sigh. I don't know, it should've been mentioned somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/matthewschrager/Repository/blob/master/Repository.FileSystem/FileSystemRepository.cs) for this package you can see that the `FileSystemRepository<>` class is in the `Repository.FileSystem` namespace, not just in `Repository`. So you need to either reference the full namespace or simply add:

```
using Repository.FileSystem;
```

Comment: Aye, that's how I usually do it, but it doesn't work. There is no FileSystem namespace under Repository. VS should be able to suggest it but as you see in the picture it just suggests creating a new class for it...